# Missing frames on shared libraries on ARM

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, arm, coredump

I'm currently working on a debugging environment, and I'm have trouble creating valid core files on ARM where the crash that caused a segmentation fault occurred on shared library code.

It seems that when there's a call to a function in a shared library, the frame pointer gets lost.

I've checked all the gcc flags I could think of. I'm not using any optimizations, not using -fomit-frame-pointer and I've tried using -rdynamic, all without success. Also, I'm not using abort(), since I read it is somewhat problematic on ARM since the frame information isn't saved since the function does not return. Instead, I'm using memset(NULL, 0, 1) to get the segmentation fault.

I'm using an arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnuabi toolchain that I compiled myself using crosstool-NG's default cortex-a8 configuration. (gcc 4.4.3, gsb 6.8). On the host machine (Ubuntu), everything works fine.

The output of GDB is like so (after loading all the shared libraries via set solib-search-path.) I omitted unrelevant output for readability.

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt full

Thread 1 (process 535):
#0 0x402ff624 in memset () from <my libc path>
No Symbol table info available.
#1 0x4011f60c in my_asserting_func () at src1.cc:5
No locals.
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

src1.cc:

```
#include <src1.h>
#include <string.h>
void my_asserting_func(void) 
{ 
    memset(NULL, 0, 1); 
}
```

main.cc:

```
#include <src1.h>
int main(void)
{
    my_asserting_func();
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be much appriciated,

Andrew.

PS: using objump, here's the disassembly of the my_asserting_func function:

```
00000654 <_Z17my_asserting_funcv>:
654:    e1a0c00d        mov      ip, sp
658:    e92dd800        push     {fp, ip, lr, pc}
65c:    e24cb004        sub      fp, ip, #4
660:    e3a00000        mov      r0, #0
664:    e3a01000        mov      r1, #0
668:    e3a02001        mov      r2, #1
66c:    ebffffb1        bl       538 <_init+0x38>
670:    e89da800        ldm      sp, {fp, sp, pc}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the disassembly? That might give you some clues why gdb does not seem to be able to walk the stack.

Comment: @80x25: I've posted the assembly code of my_asserting_func. Unfortunately, I'm not so savy when it comes to assembly, so any help would be much appriciated. Thanks, Andrew.

Comment: Hmm, nothing sticks out as a problem in that function's assembly. It would also be useful to look at the disassembly of main as well. I would say ask a question on a gdb mailing list maybe, this may be a bug in gdb, or they will at least be able to tell you more about why gdb is failing. @Andrew: