# Heap profiling on ARM

Tags: embedded, profiling, arm, heap-memory

I am developing a GUI-heavy C++ application on a Freescale MX51-based board Linux 2.6.35. **I would like to perform heap profiling.**

Unfortunately, all heap profiling tools I have found have either been too intrusive or ostensibly non-working on ARM. Specific tools I've tried:

- **[Valgrind Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)**: unworkable on my platform due to the platform's feeble CPU. The 80% CPU time overhead introduced by Massif causes a range of problems in my application that cannot be compensated for.
- **[gperftools](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/heapprofile.html)** (formerly Google Performance Tools) tcmalloc: All features of this rather un-intrusive, library-based `libc malloc()` replacement work on my target *except* for the heap profiler. To rephrase, the thread caching allocator works but the profiler does not. I'll explain the failure mode of the profiler below for anyone curious.

Can anyone suggest a set of replacement tools for performing C++ heap profiling on ARM platforms? Ideal output would ultimately be a directed allocation graph, similar to what gperftools' tcmalloc outputs. Low resource utilization is a must- my platform is highly resource constrained.

---

**Failure mode of gperftools' tcmalloc explained:**

I'm providing this information only for those that are curious; I do not expect a response. I'm seeing something similar to gperftools' issue #407 below, except on ARM rather than x86. 
Specifically, I always get the message "Hooked allocator frame not found, returning empty trace." I spent some time debugging the issue and it appears that, when dynamically linking the tcmalloc library, frame pointers at the boundary between my application and the dynamic library are null- the stack cannot be walked "above" the call into the dynamic library.

gperftools issue #407: https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/issues/410

stackoverflow user seeing similar problems on ARM: [Missing frames on shared libraries on ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231089/missing-frames-on-shared-libraries-on-arm)

Comment: Wow, so 512MB is "highly resource constrained"...

Comment: Echoing my thoughts coming from GBA/DS programming :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heaps.  Many ways to do them, but I've only run across 3 main types that matter in embedded land:

1. Linked list heaps.  Each alloc is tracked in a "used" list.  Once freed, they are dropped into a "free" list.  On freeing, adjacent blocks of free memory are "joined" into larger pieces.  Allocs can be any size.  Each alloc and free is a O(N) op as it has to traverse the free list to give you a piece of memory plus break the free block into a size close to what you asked for while leaving the remaining block in the free list.  Because of the increasing overhead per alloc, this system cannot be used by itself on smaller systems.  This also tends to cause memory fragmentation over time if steps aren't taken to minimize it.
2. Fixed size (unit) heaps.  You break your heap into equal size (smaller) parts.  This wastes memory a bit, depending on how big the chunks are (and how many different sized, fixed allocator heaps you create), but alloc and free are both O(1) time operations.  No searching, no joining.  This style is often combined with the first one for "small object allocations" as the engines I've worked with have 95% of their allocations below a set size (say 256 bytes).  This way, you use the unit heap for small allocs for huge speed and only minimal memory loss, while using the list heap for larger allocs.  No external fragmentation of memory either.
3. Relocatable memory heaps.  You don't give out pointers to memory, but handles.  That way, behind the scenes, you can change memory pointers when needed to remove fragmentation or whatever.  High overhead.  High pain the the @$$ quotient as it's easy to abuse and get dangling pointer all over.  Also added overhead for each memory dereference.  But wanted to mention it.

There's some basic patterns.  You can find all sorts of libs out in the wild that use them and also have built in statistics for number of allocs, fragmentation, and other useful stats.  It's also not the hard to roll your own really, though I'd not recommend it for anything outside of satisfying curiosity as debugging without a working malloc is painful indeed.  Adding thread support is pretty straightforward as well, but again, downloading a ready made solution is the better choice.

The above info applies to all platforms, ARM or otherwise, though most of my experience has been on low level ARM stuff so the above info is battle tested for your platform.  Hope this helps!